# Error sending assets to Binance address with python/web3

Tags: python, web3py, bsc, bep20

I am trying to send BNB from a Trust-Wallet with a python script to my binance account.

Simple function:

```
def send_bnb(to_public, from_public, from_secret, amount):
    nonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(from_public)
    tx = {
        'chainId': 97,
        'to': to_public,
        'nonce': nonce,
        'value': web3.toWei( amount,'ether'),
        'gas': 21000,
        'gasPrice': web3.toWei('50','gwei')
    }
    signed_tx = web3.eth.account.signTransaction( tx, from_secret)
    return web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
```

This works fine between two Trust-Wallet addresses, but fails if I try to send to my binance address.

Error is:

> TypeError: Transaction had invalid fields: {'to': <to_public>}

The cause may be connected to the use of upper and lower case letters in the address, as I get the same error, if I convert the working Trust-Wallet address to lower case.
But I found no hints on that so far.

Answer (score 1):

After some more research I found the solution in the [Web3.py Documentation](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html). To me, it's not clearly stated there, that addresses **must** have an EIP55 checksum. But as the API provides functions to check and create these, I thought I give it a try, and it worked!

So after adding an additional line at the beginning of the function:

```
to_public=web3.toChecksumAddress(to_public)
```

it worked.